# applying filters on controls

Tags: jquery

On the click of a table row, I am performing some action.

However I want a filter to be applied. If my tr contains another tr or a table inside it, the click should not be valid for that row

```
$("#tbl1 tr").filter(function() {
    //?? 
}).click(function(){ 
    //alert
});
```

What do i write in the filter?

UPDATE: Never mind. I applied a class and solved it.

Comment: Use below filter:
$(#tbl1").children("tr")

Comment: I tried it.however now the click does not occur for any cell of the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target `<tr>` nodes on sub-tables, use:

```
$("#tbl1 tr:not(:has(table))")
```

If you only want to target them on your main table, try:

```
$("#tbl1 > tbody > tr:not(:has(table))")
```

`tbody` is added to your table implicitly, that's why `$(#tbl1").children("tr")` didn't work.

See also: [JQuery tbody question - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624018/jquery-tbody-question-asp-net)